# Creating a method that iterates through a list to do an action

Tags: c#, list

I have an interface called IEvent and a List[IEvent]. Is there a way that I could create a method that performs one action on each element of this list without having to create a separate class? From what I've read, it's a bad idea to inherit from generic lists and I don't think an extension method is appropriate either. For example:

```
// Is it possible to create this without having to create another class that just contains the list and this method?
public void Execute(IList<IEvent> eventList)
{
    foreach (IEvent myEvent in eventList)
    {
        myEvent.Execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use *extension methods*:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void Execute(this IList<IEvent> eventList)
    {
        foreach (IEvent myEvent in eventList)
        {
            myEvent.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, any instance of `IList<IEvent>` will be able to call this method like if it were part of `IList<IEvent>`:

```
listOfIEvent.Execute();
```

### Some suggestion

My advise is you should extend `IEnumerable<IEvent>`, and since `IList<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you'll be able to call the whole extension method anyway:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void Execute(this IEnumerable<IEvent> eventList)
    {
        foreach (IEvent myEvent in eventList)
        {
            myEvent.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it good practice to define extension methods that do not use a generic type?

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, absolutely. Extension methods have nothing to do with generics. Maybe you thought this because this feature was introduced with LINQ to extend `IEnumerable<T>` implementations.

Comment: OK, just making sure that it was intended for that. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew Extension methods are useful when you want to provide more methods to a class for which you don't have the source code. Also, in your case: you just want to provide an special behavior for certain types. Indeed, extension methods used the right way are an extremely useful feature!

Comment: Should I rename the extension class to EnumerableExtensions or something like that?

Comment: @Andrew Yeah, why not. Actually, extension method class identifier is useless unless you need to call a method using reflection or calling it directly using the static class. How you call it is absolutely up to you. The "Extensions" suffix isn't mandatory, it's just a naming convention

Answer (score 1):

Not actually. Everything should be inside a class. But the simpliest what you can do - implement that method as an [extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).